# Dear @MonicaCellio, did you roll back my proposed tag wiki on purpose?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, rollbacks

Dear @MonicaCellio,

First of all, I commend you for all the questions you ask, the answers you provide, and administration work you do around here. Thank you! Much appreciated.

I wonder: Did you roll back [my proposed "alacrity-for-mitzvot" tag wiki](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/29270/revisions) on purpose? Also, did Stack Exchange offer you any option to leave a comment at the time you did the rollback?

All the best.

[**Edit:** I have now created a related question. ["Should the 'alacrity-for-mitzvot' tag exist? If so, what should its scope be?"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1708/should-the-alacrity-for-mitzvot-tag-exist-if-so-what-should-its-scope-be)]

Comment: See chat here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9783061#9783061 and note there is no option to leave a custom edit text in a rollback.

Comment: It might actually make more sense to start the chat here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9782945#9782945

Comment: But please note that there are two or three cross-conversations happening. One is about Sha'atnez checking in Chicago.

Comment: Also, please note, that while I raised an objection, I meant it in the most constructive way possible. And two other regular users, including one mod, agreed with me.

Comment: @SethJ: No offense taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unforgettableid, I apologize for the confusion and any distress this caused.  I did roll it back; I had approved it and then it was pointed out in chat that I didn't have the best understanding of the subject, so I realized I should have left it for others to decide.  Unfortunately, rolling back an edit does not provide the chance to explain the edit (the way a regular edit does), nor are there comments on tag wikis.  I should have looked harder for a way to explain it to you.

Please see this [chat log](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9782945#9782945).  I propose that this question be used to figure out whether we want this tag and, if so, what its scope should be.

Comment: It caused no distress whatsoever, just some wonderment. :) Anyway, all is forgiven. About your final point: To make things simpler, why don't we start a new question here on Meta? The text of the question could be, as you suggested, something like: "Should the [tag:alacrity-for-mitzvot] tag exist? If so, what should its scope be?"

Comment: @unforgettableid http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Dear all: For future reference, mods can send public messages to anyone, and in most cases, non-moderators can also send public messages to a user of their choice. Curious? If so: Moderators, please see ["Contacting users"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet/119114#119114) on the Moderator Cheat Sheet. Non-moderators, please see points 1 and 4 in [the answer to "What are the rules for when chat messages appear in a user's inbox?"](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/939).

Comment: @DoubleAA: Shouldn't I leave the matter up to MonicaCellio?

Comment: @unforgettableid, please go ahead and ask.  You can describe your vision for the tag there as part of that.  Thanks!

Comment: Done. Please see: ["Should the 'alacrity-for-mitzvot' tag exist? If so, what should its scope be?"](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1708/should-the-alacrity-for-mitzvot-tag-exist-if-so-what-should-its-scope-be)