# Should the "alacrity-for-mitzvot" tag exist? If so, what should its scope be?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Should the [alacrity-for-mitzvot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alacrity-for-mitzvot) tag exist?

If so, what should its scope be? Please propose a tag wiki that you'd like us to attach to the tag.

Answer (score 4):

I think it should exist but be renamed [zerizut](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerizut), which I suspect is a better-recognized wording among those who would think to use the tag. It should be on any question explicitly about the halachic concept of *z'rizin makdimin* or the *mida* of *z'rizus*. (Not, though, on question about, e.g., doing things before *shacharis*, where the answer might cite *z'rizus* but the question doesn't mention the idea.)

---

**Edit:** (Based on the comments on this answer and the votes on this page,) I've renamed the tag [zerizut-alacrity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerizut-alacrity).

Comment: 1. How about naming it "zerizut-alacrity"? 2. Also, if the answer discusses zerizut, why can't we retroactively add the tag to the question?

Comment: Re 1, yeah, [tag:zerizut-alacrity] sounds good. Re 2, see e.g. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128.

Comment: OK; feel free to rename the tag to "zerizut-alacrity". (I don't think my 643 reputation is enough to create tag synonyms.)

Comment: Do you want to do this?

Comment: @Cnsersmoit (Scimonster) eh. It has 2 upvotes.

Comment: ... out of 27 views over a year and a half. The tag has 7 questions. I don't think it would affect anyone too much.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the tag should exist. I propose that it be a hodgepodge of three things. Please see my proposed tag wiki:

---

Use this tag when a question (or the correct answer) relate to either:

- Activity before mitzvot (commandments): e.g. eating before prayer. Or:
- Doing mitzvot earlier vs. later. Or:
- How early it's permissible to do a mitzvah (commandment).

If instead, there are two mitzvot you could do, and you wonder which to do first, use [priorities](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/priorities).

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what the *priorities* tag is for. My understanding is that the *priorities* tag is used where one thing is prioritized over another thing. Like [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/priorities-mincha-ketana-vs-mincha-gedola) for example.

Comment: @Daniel: I basically was trying to discourage people from using the new tag when there are two competing mitzvot. But feel free to edit my proposed tag wiki as you wish.